Linux audio player to use with OBS (window capture)
I'm looking for a Linux audio player that I can use with OBS (window capture) during streams, with a compact view, artist/album/song name, maybe a progress bar or remaining time, maybe the thumbnail associated with the file if it exists. It should support local playlists and shuffle.
I tried Tuna (OBS plugin) but it's a bit inconvenient, every now and then I have to recompile OBS to support the browser plugin and Tuna (once I even had to debug and patch it), I don't want to waste too much time on it.
I'm currently using qmmp but would prefer something better graphically.
